# Django: Sum on an date attribute grouped by month/year

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'd like to put this query from SQL to Django:

```
"select date_format(date, '%Y-%m') as month, sum(quantity) as hours from hourentries group by date_format(date, '%Y-%m') order by date;"
```

The part that causes problem is to group by month when aggregating. I tried this (which seemed logical), but it didn't work :

```
HourEntries.objects.order_by("date").values("date__month").aggregate(Sum("quantity"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aggregate` can only generate one aggregate value.

You can get the aggregate sum of Hours of the current month by the following query.

```
from datetime import datetime
this_month = datetime.now().month
HourEntries.objects.filter(date__month=this_month).aggregate(Sum("quantity"))
```

So, to obtain the aggregate values of HourEntry's all the months, you can loop over the queryset for all the months in the db. But it is better to use the raw sql.

```
HourEntries.objects.raw("select date_format(date, '%Y-%m') as month, sum(quantity) as hours from hourentries group by date_format(date, '%Y-%m') order by date;")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer... My raw query doesn't work so I used the python code that you gave me.

Comment: Does this really work?! Specs says that you MUST include the primary_key in RAW queries... "There is only one field that you can't leave out - the primary key field. Django uses the primary key to identify model instances, so it must always be included in a raw query. An InvalidQuery exception will be raised if you forget to include the primary key." [HERE/last paragraph](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#deferring-model-fields)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you cannot aggregate on "quantity" after using `values("date__month")`, as this leaves only "date" and "month" in the QuerySet.

Comment: You cannot even use field lookups in the parameters for values... [Field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id4)