# Count value based on same date in django query

Tags: django

am not able to sum value based on date. because the below table having same date but different time. I need to sum the value of same date.

```
        Date                        revenue
 "2017-05-22 06:49:44.246+02"          10
 "2017-05-22 16:31:10.588288+02"       12
 "2017-05-23 06:49:44.246+02"           5
 "2017-05-23 16:31:10.588288+02"        6
```

I need to get the output like below. The above table have same date but different time

```
   Date        sum
2017-05-22      22
2017-05-23      11
```

I did like this

```
 today = datetime.date.today() 
 d = xxx.filter(date__year=today.year,date__month=today.month).values('date').annotate(date_revenue=Sum('revenue'))
```

but it's not woring

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Sum on an date attribute grouped by month/year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943314/django-sum-on-an-date-attribute-grouped-by-month-year)

Answer (score 0):

i found the solutions. I mentioned the query below

```
 d = xxx.filter(date__year=today.year,date__month=today.month).extra({'date_created' : "date(date)"}).values('date_created').annotate(date_revenue=Sum('revenue'))
```